# RangeError (index) Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, runtime-error

I am getting an error and red screen while trying to click a button. RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0. I do not know how to fix this error because nothing is flagged until I run my emulator. I have attached my [image: emulation screen here]
If I need to add some code please let me know I am more than willing to. Thank you!
home_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/pages/study_page.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/pages/timer_page.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/viewmodels/study_viewmodel.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController textController = new TextEditingController();
  late String filter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    textController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        filter = textController.text;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TimeStudyApp'),
      ),
      body: Material(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                      onPressed: () {
                        textController.clear();
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      },
                    ),
                    hintText: "Search...",
                  ),
                  controller: textController,
                )),
            Expanded(
              child: StudyViewModel.studies.length > 0
                  ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: StudyViewModel.studies.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (filter == null || filter == "") {
                    return buildRow(context, index);
                  } else {
                    if (StudyViewModel.studies[index].name
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .contains(filter.toLowerCase())) {
                      return buildRow(context, index);
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  }
                },
              )
                  : Center(
                child: Text('No studies found!'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          int? nullableInterger;

          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => StudyPage(
                    title: 'Add a study',
                    selected: nullableInterger ?? 0,
                  )));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildRow(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(StudyViewModel.studies[index].name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: StudyViewModel.studies[index].tasks.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int taskIndex) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(StudyViewModel.studies[index].tasks[taskIndex].name),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
              subtitle: Text(
                  StudyViewModel.studies[index].tasks[taskIndex].elapsedTime),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                    Icons.timer
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => TimerPage(
                              task: StudyViewModel
                                  .studies[index].tasks[taskIndex])));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                  Icons.edit
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => StudyPage(
                            title: StudyViewModel.studies[index].name,
                            selected: index)));
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                  Icons.delete
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Text('Do you wish to delete this study?'),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                            child: Text('Accept'),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              StudyViewModel.studies.removeAt(index);
                              await StudyViewModel.saveFile();
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),
                          FlatButton(
                            child: Text('Cancel'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

study_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/models/study.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/models/task.dart';
import 'package:timestudy_test/viewmodels/study_viewmodel.dart';

class StudyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int selected;

  StudyPage({required this.title, required this.selected});

  @override
  State createState() => StudyPageState();
}

class StudyPageState extends State<StudyPage> {
  late Study study;
  late TextField nameField;
  TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController();
  late TextField taskNameField;
  TextEditingController taskNameController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    nameField = new TextField(
      controller: nameController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Study name'),
    );
    taskNameField = new TextField(
      controller: taskNameController,
      decoration:
      InputDecoration(labelText: 'Task name'),
    );
    if(widget.selected != null) {
      study = StudyViewModel.studies[widget.selected];
      nameController.text = study.name;
    } else {
      study = new Study(
          name: "",
          tasks: <Task>[]
      );
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Material(
            child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0), child: nameField),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Tasks:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: Text('Add a task'),
                                content: taskNameField,
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text('Cancel'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text('Accept'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if(taskNameController.text == ""){
                                        errorDialog(context, 'Please enter a task name!');
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          study.tasks.add(new Task(
                                              name: taskNameController.text,
                                              elapsedTime:
                                              StudyViewModel.milliToElapsedString(
                                                  0)));
                                          taskNameController.clear();
                                        });
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: study.tasks.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(study.tasks[index].name),
                        trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              study.tasks.removeAt(index);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ), Spacer(),
                Center(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      child: Text('Save'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (nameController.text == "") {
                          errorDialog(context, 'Please enter a study name!');
                        } else {
                          if (study.tasks.length < 1) {
                            errorDialog(context, 'Please add at least one task!');
                          } else {
                            study.name = nameController.text;
                            if (widget.selected != null) {
                              StudyViewModel.studies[widget.selected] = study;
                              await StudyViewModel.saveFile();
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            } else {
                              if (StudyViewModel.checkName(nameController.text)) {
                                errorDialog(context, 'Study name already taken!');
                              } else {
                                StudyViewModel.studies.add(study);
                                await StudyViewModel.saveFile();
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ))
              ],
            ),
            )));
  }

  void errorDialog(BuildContext context, String message) async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Close'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add your code snippet

Comment: @Liam Hemphil add your code?

Comment: I just added the code

Comment: the error happens once I hit the icons.add button and also included the study page dart file as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          int? nullableInterger; 
// the issue is here you need to assign value
// the nullableInterger is use here as nothing.. declare it on state level and
// assign it when your listview builder done so the value of nullable integer is
// changed and passing value as argument will not be 0 and this error will not appear again

          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => StudyPage(
                    title: 'Add a study',
                    selected: nullableInterger ?? 0,
                  )));
        },
      ),
```

Comment: So add the nullableInterger to the top of the code near HomePageState extends State<HomePage> or add it to the study_page file?

Comment: yes you can add it inside the State<HomePage> but you need to assign the value to it when you jump to next it will get a value with it

Comment: what value should I assign to the nullableInterger? both 0 and 1 didn't work

Comment: 1st of all if you are not using this variable please avoid to use it on both screen.... you not need to passargumnt if you dont want to use it.. it seems like the argumnt is not nessesory so please remove it

Comment: The selected variable is used in both and the nullableInterger is only used on the home page screen

Comment: Which one should I remove?

Comment: class StudyPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final String title;

  final int selected; /// first find where this variable use.. if it is use then before use try to print it


  StudyPage({required this.title, required this.selected});


  @override

  State createState() => StudyPageState();

}

Comment: if you share your code i will fix it if it is possible..